# How do I implement openscad's linear extrusion operator (with twist and scale) in cadquery?

Tags: openscad, cadquery

I'm translating some OpenSCAD code to CadQuery.

I'm having trouble with a `linear_extrude` call that contains both an angle and a scaling factor. Now an angle is simple in CadQuery (`twistExtrude`), and so is scaling (copy the 2D structure to another workspace, scale it, then `loft`).

How do I do both? OpenSCAD example:

```
linear_extrude(30,twist=3*360,scale=0.2) square(8);
```

[image: resulting structure]